# Unable to center content using margin auto

Tags: html, css

When the screen size is less than 768px, the 3 boxes are aligned to the left. I'm having a hard time trying to make them appear center.

I managed to center it by setting margin-left to some value however, it isn't responsive afterwards.

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
      <div class="row bg_color">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 stats_box">
               <h3>2015/16</h3>
               <hr>
               <ul>
                  <li>The Best FIFA Men's Player 2016</li>
                  <li>FIFA Club World Cup</li>
                  <li>France Football Ballon D'Or 2016</li>
                  <li>UEFA Best Player in Europe</li>
                  <li>UEFA Euro 2016 (Portugal)</li>
                  <li>UEFA Champions League (Real Madrid)</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 stats_box">
               <h3>2014/15</h3>
               <hr>
               <ul>
                  <li>Pichichi Award</li>
                  <li>European Golden Boot 2015</li>
                  <li>FIFA Ballon D'Or 2014</li>
                  <li>Globe Soccer Best Player of the Year</li>
                  <li>Globe Soccer Fan's Favourite Player Award</li>
                  <li>IFFHS Trophy for Best Striker  on the planet</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 stats_box">
               <h3>2013/14</h3>
               <hr>
               <ul>
                  <li>Club World Cup</li>
                  <li>BBC Overseas Sports  Personality Award</li>
                  <li>World's Top  Goalscorer 2013</li>
                  <li>Pichichi Award</li>
                  <li>Best Player, Best Forward in La Liga</li>
                  <li>UEFA Best Player in Europe</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>

</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .bg_color {
    background: #ECFEAA;
}

.stats_box {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px 40px 40px;
    max-width: 400px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 6px;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .stats_box {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
}
```

Any possible solution for this? And why isn't **margin:0 auto** not working here?

Link to the code: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/srujan369/pen/GEoqPE?editors=1100)

Comment: Since you seem to change your original codepen every now and then, it doesn't match the code within the question, so I deleted all my comment and answer, as there is no way an answer can relate if you change the original values.

Answer (score 2):

`margin: 0 auto;` does not work because you have `float: left;` on the `.stats_box`. So you can handle this a couple of ways.

**1)** Remove `float` when 768px <, [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfx254wx/)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .stats_box {
    float: none;
    margin: 15px auto;
  }
}
```

**2)** do not work "directly" under the `col-xs-12`, have a container inside and have that have the max-width and all other styling, set `margin: 0 auto;` on that. This would be my suggested solution. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/p72yef6t/1)

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="stats_box">
      <h3>2015/16</h3>
      <hr>
      <ul>
        <li>The Best FIFA Men's Player 2016</li>
        <li>FIFA Club World Cup</li>
        <li>France Football Ballon D'Or 2016</li>
        <li>UEFA Best Player in Europe</li>
        <li>UEFA Euro 2016 (Portugal)</li>
        <li>UEFA Champions League (Real Madrid)</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .stats_box {
    margin: 15px auto;
  }
}
```

**3)** Use flexbox when 768px <, [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/9sjg2cf5/1/)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .row {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
    }
```

**4)** Use inline (I would not suggest this solution so no example)

Comment: The first 2 is perfectly fine :), so plus 1 ... and the second version combined with inline-block is better than flexbox (based on browser compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your CSS to center the 3 boxes.

```
.row.bg_color {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: That will break _bootstraps_ grid for starters, and as well make all items flow horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

try this for 768px, it works

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .stats_box {
   width: 100%;
   left:50%;
   transform:translateX(-50%);
 }
}
```

Hope this will help!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all change your mark up just like following and update css part

you are using nesting class with bootstrap classes and the bootstrap classes are using `float:left` that's why your code is not working.

Working fiddle **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zvfvm6q/25/)**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .stats_box {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto;
  }
}
```

```css
.bg_color {
  background: #ECFEAA;
}

.stats_box {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px 40px 40px;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .stats_box {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="row bg_color ">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="stats_box"> <!-- Place here the class same as rest -->
        <h3>2015/16</h3>
        <hr>
        <ul>
          <li>The Best FIFA Men's Player 2016</li>
          <li>FIFA Club World Cup</li>
          <li>France Football Ballon D'Or 2016</li>
          <li>UEFA Best Player in Europe</li>
          <li>UEFA Euro 2016 (Portugal)</li>
          <li>UEFA Champions League (Real Madrid)</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="stats_box">
        <h3>2015/16</h3>
        <hr>
        <ul>
          <li>The Best FIFA Men's Player 2016</li>
          <li>FIFA Club World Cup</li>
          <li>France Football Ballon D'Or 2016</li>
          <li>UEFA Best Player in Europe</li>
          <li>UEFA Euro 2016 (Portugal)</li>
          <li>UEFA Champions League (Real Madrid)</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="stats_box">
        <h3>2015/16</h3>
        <hr>
        <ul>
          <li>The Best FIFA Men's Player 2016</li>
          <li>FIFA Club World Cup</li>
          <li>France Football Ballon D'Or 2016</li>
          <li>UEFA Best Player in Europe</li>
          <li>UEFA Euro 2016 (Portugal)</li>
          <li>UEFA Champions League (Real Madrid)</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this CSS code in your style,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.stats_box {
    width: 100%;
}
.center-col{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
}
```

and in the HTML,

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 stats_box center-col">
```

Please make sure that you removed the `margin:200px`in `.stats_box`. Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add **media query** in your **css**.

A **media query** consists of an optional media type and zero or more expressions that limit the style sheets' scope by using media features, such as width, height, and color. Media queries, added in CSS3, let the presentation of content be tailored to a specific range of output devices without having to change the content itself.

**Syntax:**

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
   .facet_sidebar {
   display: none;
   }
}
```

You can learn it more in this site:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries